# popup remains in the occupied area although closed

Tags: javascript

I encounter the following problem: I made a simple implementation of a popup, but when I close it and put the cusrsor on the blank area where previously was the popup, I can now click there (in the blank area) and the popup appears again. That is, it seems as if it does not close and it remains in the area which previously it was occuping. Could please someone help me because i do not understand how to make it close permantly.

```js
function fPopUp() {
  var PopUp = document.getElementById("IDPopUp");
  PopUp.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
    position: absolute;
    /*display: block;*/
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    /*display: none;*/
    width: 500px;
    background-color: grey;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;} 
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

```html
<button id="bAbout" onclick="fPopUp()">PopUp</button>

<div class="popup" onclick="fPopUp()">
  <span class="popuptext" id="IDPopUp">"some text"</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Because using `visibility:hidden` an element still takes up space in the page. Not the same as using `display:none` and element has no dimensions then. Read up on how the `visibility` property works

Comment: Now there is no popup at all

Comment: You need to use `display:block` to show it

Comment: I did it but now there is no popup at all

Comment: Please update the code in your question. FYI, CSS does not support inline `//` comments

Comment: Sorry, Phil. You are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `visibility: hidden` will hide the element from sight but the element will still occupy its predetermined space on the document. To completely hide the element, you need to use `display: none` but this doesn't play well with animations.

Your code makes things much more complicated than they have to be, so allow me to make some amendments. Here are a few suggestions:

1. Put the `id` on the actual popup instead of its content. You're trying to show/hide the popup, not its text.
2. This is a rather simple animation, so a simple CSS transition will do just fine.
3. Use `pointer-events: none` to make your element unresponsive to mouse events. The element will still occupy the space it normally does, but nobody will know.

```js
function fPopUp() {
  IDPopUp.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: grey;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup.show {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<button id = "bAbout" onclick = "fPopUp()">PopUp</button>

<div id = "IDPopUp" class = "popup" onclick = "fPopUp()">
  <span class = "popuptext">"some text"</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Angel Politis, for the commets too. It works fine now !!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help 